# Alternative to database for storing data?

Tags: c#, database

I was using SQL Server Compact Edition (local-database) for my application. But while I was using the entity framework, I kept experiencing a very annoying UpdateException. My database only has two small tables with a foreign key relationship linking them together. So I am asking if there is any alternative to a database? Or is that the only option?
UPDATE:
[Here](http://i45.tinypic.com/2yvkv80.jpg) is the EDMX map.
Here is the stacktrace for the exception:
`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message=Cannot create instance of 'MainWindow' defined in assembly 'AssignmentOrganizer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'AssignmentOrganizer;component/MainWindow.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetElementAndFlags(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementStartRecord, Object& element, ReaderFlags& flags, Type& delayCreatedType, Int16& delayCreatedTypeId)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
       at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at AssignmentOrganizer.App.Main() in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AssignmentOrganizer\AssignmentOrganizer\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       InnerException: System.Data.UpdateException
            Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the InnerException for details.
            Source=System.Data.Entity
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
                 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
                 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptChangesDuringSave)
                 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
                 at AssignmentOrganizer.App_Data.AssignmentRepository.CreateAssignment(Assignment assignmentToCreate) in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AssignmentOrganizer\AssignmentOrganizer\App_Data\AssignmentRepository.cs:line 20
                 at AssignmentOrganizer.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AssignmentOrganizer\AssignmentOrganizer\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 34
            InnerException: System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException
                 Message=An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
                 Source=System.Data.Entity
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
                      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator translator, Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
                      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
                      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
                 InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
                      Message=Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact.
                      Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity
                      StackTrace:
                           at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateReturningSql(StringBuilder commandText, DbModificationCommandTree tree, ExpressionTranslator translator, DbExpression returning)
                           at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateInsertSql(DbInsertCommandTree tree, List`1& parameters, Boolean isLocalProvider)
                           at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.SqlGenerator.GenerateSql(DbCommandTree tree, List`1& parameters, CommandType& commandType, Boolean isLocalProvider)
                           at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
                           at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
                           at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
                           at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree)
                           at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
                      InnerException: 
`

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of data you are storing in your two tables? I would say XML files, but it would be best to see some data examples before jumping on an answer.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to figure out what is causing the _UpdateException_ and fix that instead of dumping the database?

Comment: Does my update answer your questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are always alternatives. The question is whether they're better than a database. You could store your data in XML, or your own file format, etc. Then you'd have to write appropriate querying, updating code etc. That *may* be fine - but we can't possibly say without more information.

However, before even considering another solution, I would get to the bottom of why you're seeing an exception. You may well have some behavior you didn't really anticipate which could equally hurt you when you've changed your storage layer - and it may well be harder to diagnose at that point. Once you've worked out why your current approach isn't working, you'll be in a much better position to know whether or not it's worth changing.

Answer (score 1):

XML files will work if you don't have too terribly much data.  Hard to say though, without more knowledge of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Well the main reason to use a Relational Database is to ensure data integrity and **Relationships**.

If you can live without the foreign key constraint, just store it as a flat file (excel, xml, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) is also a good option.  No need to install a server.

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition doesn't require a server either.  Like SQLite, it runs in-process.

Comment: Doesn't the actual SQL Server (Service-based database) requires you to install SQL Server? I think?

Answer (score 1):

There was probably a good reason you picked a DB implementation, specially if relationship and integrity are important. Try to figure out why you're hitting the exception - if it's a SQL CE thing, then you could consider alternative like ESE (Jet) which is part of all Windows installs and is much more robust.