# Developing a Java Application with database

Tags: java

Sorry for this trivial question, but I am new to programming and I wanted to create a Java app that can be distributed to other computers without having to install database on that computer.

The app is similar to an address book app where you store details about a person. Is there a way to create something like that using netbeans which does not require a database or is there any other way to go about it..

I have searched for answers, but I guess I am not searching for the right keywords which I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me with.

PS: I know how to create an app like that in netbeans which is connected to a database (Mysql or Postgresql) but they cannot be moved from one computer to other? Or can it be? I don't know.

Thanks you in advance..

Comment: Used JDBC in your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I want to make a Java program relying on a database and which is lightweight and which doesn't appear to have any other dependencies than a JVM, I use [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (JavaDB).

It is a pure Java database engine which you can embed in your Java application. Very small footprint. I usually package the program with a SQL file for creating the database structure and another one for populating it. Worth taking a look IMO.

**EDIT:** Just saving you the search... If you try DerbyDB, there is a little something you want to know (in case you also have that syndrome of not reading manuals)... When you close Derby, it throws exceptions if it went wrong AND if it went well. You'll receive exceptions with `exception.getSQLState().equals("08006")` and `"XJ015"`. These are for *successful* shutdown; don't mind them. On connection to Derby, you'll get `exception.getErrorCode() == 40000` if the database was not yet created; just create it. (These exceptions are all SQLException instances.)

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I believe I should be able to develop what I want with DerbyDB. I would have reped you guys, but I dont have enough rep myself(atleast 15) to rep you :(

Answer (score 1):

If your application has a database back-end, then you will require database software on either the computer where the application is running, or on a remote server.

If you want the application and database to be portable, you can use something like [SQLite](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) (an embedded SQL database engine) or even flat files.

Comment: Yes, I think thats exactly what I want..(application and database to be portable) I will look into SQLite and see if I can embed it in the java application.. Thanks for that..

Comment: Also, you could use HSQLDB (http://hsqldb.org/). More or less, the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to move the database to any computer, what you can do is write some SQL scripts to generate the tables(and populate, if necessary) needed for application, and it can work on any computer.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer..but doesn't that mean that the other computers will need to have database installed on them? Also will the data entered on the previous computer to that application be available to the other computers that I will be moving it to.

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is to have a database embedded into this application?

Comment: Yes, database has to be installed in other computers for that, and for the previous data, as I said you can write scripts for that too.

Comment: For alternate solution to database, check this link out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231208/alternative-to-database-for-storing-data