# java how to access a database that is in webserver across the internet?

Tags: java, database, webserver

If I have a database in a webserver(over the internet) and i have a java desktop application, in how many ways can i access that database. Please could you provide me with links for detailed article.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing a Java Application with database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273367/developing-a-java-application-with-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the database, but...

Most databases will allow you to access them remotely. You specify the URL and port when you set up your database connection in your Java program.

However, if you do not have control of the database, then this can be difficult. It is also a BIG security risk, unless you lock down the access via the HOSTS value of the user_id you are connecting with.

There are other work-around approaches, like VPNs, Tunnels and even fronting the database with a Web Service, but none of these are likely to give you the same level of access that the first option will.

Comment: well, I am quite newbie to java and know only basics. could you explain how this HOST value is? Is it like 'localhost' that i use for my localserver. I am going to create a website as well as desktop application for some client. Can i connect through an web api? would it be a security risk?

Comment: Its not a java specific thing, it is a database configuration thing. Each database will have a user name and password. Most databases allow you to configure if that user can be used on the localhost only, or on a specific IP. It is used to ensure that only requests from a certain IP address are allowed to access database content (such as the application server accessing the database from a remote machine).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link from oracle:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Its very simple and easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend to use [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org), it easy to define any URL, to any database provider in Hibernate config file.
E.g

property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://189.234.223.89:3306/dbname"/>
property name="username" value="root"/>
property name="password" value="pwd"/>